# Applying an array to Morris.js charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, morris.js

I have an array of data generated from a php db call:

```
boxData[0] = "period : 2012 W1";
boxData[1] = "1:33"; 
boxData[2] = "2:36"; 
boxData[3] = "3:23"; 
boxData[4] = "4:37";
```

I want to apply this to the data key of a morris bar chart by a parameter. If I hard-code it, it works... but i want to just slip the area data into the data field, as I have doens with the ykey and label fields, where I have slipped in arrays no problems.

Hardcoded..

```
Morris.Bar({
  element : 'morris-bar-chart',
  data : [{
    period : "2012 W1",
    1: 33, 
    2: 34,
    3: 35,
    4: 32
  }],
  xkey : 'period',
  ykeys : boxKey,
  labels : boxLabels,
  hideHover : 'auto',
  resize : true
});
```

What I want...

```
Morris.Bar({
  element : 'morris-bar-chart',
  data : boxData,
  xkey : 'period',
  ykeys : boxKey,
  labels : boxLabels,
  hideHover : 'auto',
  resize : true
});
```

I see that data should be an array of objects so how do I get boxData to be that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always format your data post retrieval like...

```
var boxDataObj = {};

while (boxData.length > 0){
    var temp = cleanData(boxData.shift());
    boxDataObj[temp.index] = temp.value;
}

function cleanData(el) {
    var trimmed = el.split(':');
    return {
        index: trimmed[0].trim(),
        value: trimmed[1].trim()
    };
}
```

if you need the value to be an int just parseInt.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually that worked a treat! Thanks so much. I didn't understand the problem before actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object prototype.

```
morrisBar{
element:'',
data:[],
.
.
.
}
```

Then when you want to create a new object, you can do

```
var foo = new Object.create(morrisBar);
```

Where you can then do

```
foo.data =  boxData;
```

And specify other data members of the class that way.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood your question, so sorry if I have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `boxData` array to an object:

```
for (var i = 0, l = boxData.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    boxDataObj.period = boxData[0].split(' : ')[1];
  } else {
    boxDataObj[i] = boxData[i].split(':')[1];
  }
}
```

**boxDataObj output**

```
{
  period: "2012 W1",
  1: 33, 
  2: 34,
  3: 35,
  4: 32
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg2p/1/)

and then add the object to a new array for use as the value of the data key in the Morris.js configuration object:

```
Morris.Bar({
  element : 'morris-bar-chart',
  data : [boxDataObj],
  xkey : 'period',
  ykeys : boxKey,
  labels : boxLabels,
  hideHover : 'auto',
  resize : true
});
```

Comment: I tried that and get what you get my own values after the ":" Object {1: "1:32", 2: "2:33", 3: "3:34", 4: "4:35", period: "2012 W1"}.. but the chart shows the values before the :'s not the ones after...ie 33, 34 etc